# Why isn't this Firestore security rule being enforced?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have the following Firestore rules. I'm using the Admin SDK with a Service Account key to access Firestore.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{user} {
      allow read, delete: if true;
      allow update, write: if getAfter(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.resource.id)).data.AccountId is int;
    }
  }
}
```

I want to enforce the `AccountId` field as an `int` in the `users` collection, but I can still writes (and batch writes) where `AccountId` is a `string`.

I'm trying to validate the data in each document in the `users` collection.

Here's the code that will update a `user` document:

```
try {
  await db.collection('users').doc('1').set({
    AccountId: '1234'
  })

} catch(e) {
  console.log(e)
}
```

This shouldn't be allowed, since `AccountId` is not an int.

```
try {
  await db.collection('users').doc('1').set({
    AccountId: 1234
  })

} catch(e) {
  console.log(e)
}
```

This should be allowed, since `AccountId` is an int.

Using the Admin SDK, I'm able to set the `AccountId` to a `string`.

EDIT:
I have updated my rules, and I'm still able to write `AccountId` as a `string`.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{user} {
        allow read: if true;
        allow create, update: if request.resource.data.AccountId is int;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Admin SDK bypasses all security rules, unconditionally.  The rules apply to only mobile and web clients.  You will need to check in the code itself if it's doing the right thing.